# How to set number of digits for float point output in Ipython

Tags: ipython

In octave the output of float point numbers is limited by default to 4 digits (%.4f). Is there a way to set this behavior using IPython?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using numpy a lot, then [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) lets you tweak that.

Another option is to use the [magic `%precision`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision) command (only in IPython 0.11 or greater).

I guess that you can put your defaults in your [startup configuration file](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html).

Comment: This answer needs a number of modifications. Some of these URLs s do not work.

Answer (score 5):

%precision also takes a format argument, eg like this (gives you 2 digit precision and non-scientific format):

```
%precision %.2f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the precision to 6 digits, try this:

```
%precision 6
```

Comment: didn't work for me. i am printing floats in lists, and with this magic i don't get the desired precision.