# How to control the number of digits of the output in `IPython.display.Markdown`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, ipython

I using the following code (Actually similar) to create a table in Markdown using `IPython.display.Markdown`:

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown
from tabulate import tabulate
table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],
         ["Earth",6371,5973.6],
         ["Moon",1737,73.5],
         ["Mars",3390,641.85]]
Markdown(tabulate(
  table, 
  headers=["Planet","R (km)", "mass (x 10^29 kg)"]
))
```

I was wondering if there is a way to control the actual number of digits / precision of the floating numbers in the class.

Something like `:0.2f` in `f` Strings.

I tried looking at the documentation at https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Markdown yet I couldn't find any way to control it.

I know there is a magic command to control it globally: [How to set number of digits for float point output in Ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018167/how-to-set-number-of-digits-for-float-point-output-in-ipython). Yet I'm looking for something per output.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that returns a formatted value, and apply it on all elements. like so:

```
from math import round

def format_distance(value):
    return round(value, 2)
    
formatted_table = [[x[0], format_distance(x[1])] for x in table]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I found is actually configuring, in this specific case, the table generation.
According to https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate at Number formatting:

[image]

So I can use `floatfmt`.

It is not an answer in general for markdown, yet will work in the case above.